# Centering a map with Geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am teaching myself scripting and have learned a lot.  I am, however, stuck at this one point.  I am wanting to display a weather map and have it center to the users location.  Here is what I have in the body of my html so far..

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<div id="loading">Loading animation layers... <br>
 <span id="progress"></span>% done.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var map, radar, satellite;
  var animationSync;

  // GeoLocation Services
     function showLocation(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        }

     function errorHandler(err) {
        if(err.code == 1) {
           alert("Error: Access is denied!");
        }
        else if( err.code == 2) {
           alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
        }
        }

     function getLocation(){
        if(navigator.geolocation){
           // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
           var options = {timeout:60000};
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
        }
        else{
           alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
        }
        }
  // End GeoLocation Services  

  map = new aeris.maps.Map('map-canvas', {zoom: 9, center: [36.0462, -96.9942]});

  // here is what I am wanting to do instead of the above line..
  // map = new aeris.maps.Map('map-canvas', {zoom: 9, center: [latitude +',' + longitude]});
```

I can display the map perfectly if I hard code the LAT and LON but thats not what I need.  I am confident my GeoLocation routine is working as the console in my browser does not show any errors, its only when I try to center the map using LAT and LONG as variables that I have a problem.  I am hoping this is just a syntax type issue, but I just don't know enough to figure this out.  I have also tried using the *map.setCenter* command but can't figure where to use it so it works.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the last line by

```
map = new aeris.maps.Map('map-canvas', {zoom: 9, center: [latitude,   longitude]});
```

The quotes were not needed and transformed your array with 2 values in an array with a single string value

Answer (score 0):

#### Current issue

The issue right now is you're performing string concatenation with `latitude` and `longitude`.  You can just use them as normal inside the array:

```
map = new aeris.maps.Map('map-canvas', {zoom: 9, center: [latitude, longitude]});
```

#### More info that may be of use:

The thing to remember is that both these variables need to be in scope, which they currently aren't.  `latitude` and `longitude` exist only inside `showLocation()`, and to further complicate things, it's a callback which means your `new aeris.maps.Map()` will fail because neither values are set.

If you're just trying to display a map around the position of the current user, this should do it:

```
var map, radar, satellite;
var animationSync;

// GeoLocation Services
function showLocation(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    map = new aeris.maps.Map("map-canvas", {
        zoom: 9,
        center: [latitude, longitude]
    });
}

function errorHandler(err) {
    if (err.code == 1) {
        alert("Error: Access is denied!");
    } else if (err.code == 2) {
        alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
    }
}

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
        var options = {
            timeout: 60000
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
    }
}

getLocation();
```

It's a bit tricky since the action happens asynchronously, meaning anything you do with `map` have to happen after `showLocation` is called.

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I needed.  I do understand the issues of scope now, and even wondered about it when I was coding.  In some other languages, once you define a variable its universal and good all up and down the page.  I need to follow up on that concept.  The callback issue is news to me, I did not know that one at all but see your point and will look at that issue as well.